# PHP If statement always firing as true

Tags: php, if-statement

First of all, I know that this has already been asked a million times, but none of the answers I have found seem to work. I have the following if statement in my 'Header.php' page:

```
<?php
$currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    echo($currentpage);
    if($currentpage == "/recap-2013.php" || "/index.php" ) { ?>
        <script src=... a bunch of HTML
<?php } ?>
```

The idea is to insert some JS if $currentpage is equal to either recap-2013.php or index.php, and if not, to do nothing.

I've added the `echo($currentpage)` in there to check what my `REQUEST_URI` is.

The problem is, even if the request URI is /someotherpage.php, the statement evaluates as true and the JS appears in my head tag. I'm sure it's something small that I'm missing but I cannot figure out what.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your if statement logic is incorrect. What you really mean is:

```
if($currentpage == "/recap-2013.php" || $currentpage == "/index.php" ) { ?>
```

In your current logic the second expression will always be true because PHP has loose typing the string will be evaluated as a boolean and a non-empty string is always true.

Answer (score 1):

It will always FIRE as true. Why? as you can see, no matter what the outcome of the first condition it will SURELY AND ALWAYS be true at the second...

Okay let's see...

```
if($currentpage == "/recap-2013.php" || "/index.php" )
```

So first condition would be:

```
if($currentpage == "/recap-2013.php")
```

Let's say the outcome of this would be **FALSE**.

So let's proceed to the second condition:

```
if("/index.php")
```

SURELY and ALWAYS be **TRUE**!

Why? Because in conditional statements only FALSE(bool), 0, NULL, *empty string*, etc...
are considered to be false. In your situation, **"/index.php"** is not an empty string nor it is *NULL*, that is why it is always be **TRUE**.

As i've understood about your conditions, you are trying to imply:

```
if($currentpage == "/recap-2013.php" || $currentpage == "/index.php" )
```

NOTE: Always be careful with conditional statements, it always gets us programmers a lot.

Comment: Thanks! This is awesome clarification. Will definitely be avoiding that in the future